# Tomcat deployDirectory not working with shortcut

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I am new to using Apache Tomcat but I am experienced at programming in Java. I am working on a project with someone else and they created a shortcut in the apache-tomcat/webapps directory to another directory that they work on in Eclipse. When they run catalina start tomcat deploys their directory. I set mine up in a similar way however when I run catalina start it deploys all the other directories does not deploy my directory nor do I get any errors. It seems like tomcat simply ignores that my shortcut is there at all. I have looked around online and compared my setup to his and I cannot seem to find any differences. If I do not use a shortcut it seems to work. What is happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you working on linux?

Comment: no windows unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat ignores the shortcut as shortcut is created file with .lnk extension.
so tomcat ignores the file. you need to create symbolic link using mklink command from windows.
mklink /D destination_directory_name path_to_source_directory